# Django unit testing: How should one test abstract models?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

In my Django Project I have an app called 'core' which contains all my reusable model mixins / abstract models (behaviors.py), models (models.py), views (views.py) and helpers functions (utils.py):

```
core/
    __init__.py
    behaviors.py  
    models.py
    utils.py
    views.py
```

I now want to write tests for these files. For models, utils and views I just wrote unit tests like I'm used to.

I'm now uncertain how I should test the abstract models contained in behaviors.py. For example, I have this model mixin:

```py
import uuid as uuid_lib

from django.db import models


class UniversallyUniqueIdentifiable(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
    db_index=True,
    default=uuid_lib.uuid4,
    editable=False
        )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

How can you test an abstract model?
In [one of the articles](http://blog.kevinastone.com/django-model-behaviors) I used to learn about fat models, the author just tests the models in which he used the abstract models. But that feels not very DRY to me since that would mean I would have to test the adding of the UUID in each model I use it in.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to test here. This is a simple model with a single UUID field; there's no functionality to test.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought that you would have to test that the UUID gets succesfully added to classes which inherit from this model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import UniversallyUniqueIdentifiable

import uuid    


class TestUniversallyUniqueIdentifiable(TestCase):

    model = UniversallyUniqueIdentifiable

    def setUp(self):
        # Create a dummy model
        self.model = ModelBase(
            '__TestModel__' + self.model.__name__, (self.model,),
            {'__module__': self.model.__module__}
        )

        # Create the schema for our test model
        with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
            schema_editor.create_model(self.model)

    def test_mytest_case(self):

        self.model.objects.create(uuid=uuid.uuid4())
        self.assertEqual(self.model.objects.count(), 1) 

    def tearDown(self):
        # Delete the schema for the test model
        with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
            schema_editor.delete_model(self.model)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Anjaneyulu Batta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4859910/anjaneyulu-batta)'s answer is amazing but not so readable and might be less maintainable if the Django team changes the way `connection` behaves internally.

What I would do:

1. Test the abstract class' generic properties ***through*** any model using this abstract class.
2. Test that this **is subclassing** the abstract class.
3. Test the **specific properties** of this model.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 for any other model.

Example: one abstract class **`Parallelogram`** and one model using it called **`Square`**.

```
from unittest import TestCase

from tetrahedrons.models import Parallelogram, Square

class ParallelogramAbstractModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_has_four_sides(self):
        ...

    def test_parallel_opposite_sides(self):
        ...

class SquareModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_subclasses_mobel_base(self):
        self.assertTrue(issubclass(Square, Parallelogram))

    def test_equal_sides(self):
        ...
```